# group by with python and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, streamlit

i have the below dataframe i want to filter the dataframe and return result based on the user selection from a **multiselectbox** , **and grouped by name**

the selectbox is the unique value of **name** field

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

    data = {
         'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
         'name': ['peter', 'john', 'james', 'james'],
         'nickname': ['pet', 'jon','james', 'jem'],
         'mother_name': ['maria', 'linda', 'ana', 'beth'],
         'bd': ['2000-05-15', '2006-09-12', '2004-10-25',]    
     }
    
    with st.sidebar.form(key='search_form',clear_on_submit= False):
    choices =df["name"].unique().tolist()
    regular_search_term = st.multiselect(" ",choices)
    
    if st.form_submit_button("search"):
       df_result_search=df[df["name"].isin(regular_search_term)]
       df_group = df_result_search.groupby('name')
    
       st.write(df_group)
```

> if i select **james**  it return the 2 records while i need to return
> 1 record  that includes the 2 data related to **james**

how can i return this result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing value for the key `bd` in your `data` dictionnary.

You can use this :

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'name': ['peter', 'john', 'james', 'james'],
    'nickname': ['pet', 'jon', 'james', 'jem'],
    'mother_name': ['maria', 'linda', 'ana', 'beth'],
    'bd': ['2000-05-15', '2006-09-12', '2004-10-25', '2004-10-26']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

with st.sidebar.form(key='search_form', clear_on_submit=False):
    choices = df["name"].unique().tolist()
    regular_search_term = st.multiselect(" ", choices)

    if st.form_submit_button("search"):
        st.text('Filter on name')
        st.write(df[df["name"].isin(regular_search_term)])
        st.text('Filter on nickname')
        st.write(df[df["nickname"].isin(regular_search_term)])

        df_gr = df[['ID', 'nickname', 'mother_name', 'bd']
                      ].astype(str).groupby(df['name']).agg('|'.join).reset_index()
        st.text('Filter on name with grouped columns')
        st.write(df_gr[df_gr["name"].isin(regular_search_term)])
```

##### `>>> Output (in browser)`:

[image]

*I let you choose whatever type of filter/display you want between the three.*